# Optimization of a Simple Query on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have the script:

```
SELECT *, (pbct_hits + (COUNT(likes.rvw_usr_like) * 5) - (COUNT(unlikes.rvw_usr_like)) * 5) AS score
FROM tb_publications
LEFT JOIN tb_reviews_users likes ON likes.rvw_usr_fk_publication = pbct_id AND likes.rvw_usr_like IS TRUE
LEFT JOIN tb_reviews_users unlikes ON unlikes.rvw_usr_fk_publication = pbct_id AND unlikes.rvw_usr_like IS FALSE
GROUP BY pbct_id
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

I would not want to make two joins to the same table.

I believe it is possible to optimize the above script, but I'm not getting.

## Edit

The question is solved:

```
-- Final Script:
SELECT pbct.*
FROM tb_publications pbct
LEFT JOIN tb_reviews_users ON rvw_usr_fk_publication = pbct_id
GROUP BY pbct_id
ORDER BY
(
(pbct_hits * 1) +
((SUM(CASE WHEN rvw_usr_like IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 5) -
((SUM(CASE WHEN rvw_usr_like IS FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 5)
) DESC, pbct_record ASC;
```

Is based on answer of @MikeSmithDev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT pbct_id, 
score = 
  (pbct_hits + 
     ((SUM(CASE WHEN rvw_usr_like IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 5) -
     ((SUM(CASE WHEN rvw_usr_like IS FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 5))
    FROM tb_publications
    LEFT JOIN tb_reviews_users likes ON likes.rvw_usr_fk_publication = pbct_id 
    GROUP BY pbct_id
```

That should work... or do something simpler in SQL with math on php side

Answer (score 0):

I would not do the math like that in the query. I would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_publications
LEFT JOIN tb_reviews_users review_users ON review_users.rvw_usr_fk_publication = pbct_id
GROUP BY pbct_id
```

then I would manually do the math in php

```
$score = 0;
if($row['rvw_usr_like'])
   $score += 5;
```

Also, depending on whether you insert likes or display score more often, you may want to consider storing an aggregate score in the publications table.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but... Your query is incorrect. It makes sense to sort by score, as it is just an alias. Also, I would bring the data already in the query, not having to deal anything in PHP.

Comment: Fixed it to not order by score. I really encourage you to keep your sql as light as possible and do the work in php. The database usually the first thing to cause scalability issues so you want to reduce it's load as much as possible.